# Managing a list item of ListView

Tags: android, listview, view, viewgroup

I created a custom ListView. Each item in the list have one imageView and two TextView.

The code is:

```
public class PersonalList extends ListActivity{

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] name= new String[] { "Mary", "Frank",
            "John" };
    String[] surname = new String[] { "Ballak", "Doe",
            "Strip"" };
    setContentView(R.layout.member_list);

    MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, name, surname);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String name = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, "selected item: "+name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
  }

 }
```

where MySimpleArrayAdapter is:

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
      private final Context context;
      private final String[] name;
      private final String[] surname;

      public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] name, String[] surname)
      {
          super(context, R.layout.list_row, name);
          this.context = context;
          this.name= name;
          this.surname = surname;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        TextView nameView= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        TextView surnameView= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label1);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        nameView.setText(name[position]);
        surnameView.setText(surname[position]);

        return rowView;
      }
  }
```

Calling the following code from `onListItemClick`:

```
  Toast.makeText(this, "selected item: "+name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I obtain for the first item a message in toast like this:

```
  "selected item: Mary"
```

What can I do in order to obtain the following result?

```
  "selected item: Mary Ballak"
```

Comment: I highly recommend watching Android's Romain Guy [discuss adapters and efficiency](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) for some pro-tips and because you are not using the ArrayAdapter's unique methods at all I suggest extending a BaseAdapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you first & last names:

```
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String name = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, "selected item: " + ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label)).getText().toString() + " " + ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label1)).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
  }
```

In addition - you can get the index from the `onItemClick` and get the String from the arrays (name/surname) - if you'll save the array as members of your `Activity`

Something like: `String text = mName[position] + " " + msurName[position];`

Comment: Thank you. Now it works good. But why getListAdapter().getItem(position); return the item of the first String array (name)?

Comment: The Adapter iterates over an ArrayList of Strings. The getView() method will be called the number of times as the List's items. In your case - though you did not implement your Adapter like it, the list is the list of the names.
P.S if this answer helped you - please be kind and accept it.. :0 thanks!